# Get last message between current user and others from sql

Tags: mysql, database, messaging

I want to retrieve the last messages between current user and others and display it in the user's messages page like how facebook does. I used this

```
select *
from ch_messages
where receiver='$current_user_id' or sender='$current_user_id' && (least(sender, receiver), greatest(sender, receiver), f_msg_date)     
in 
(
    select 
       least(sender, receiver) as x, greatest(sender, receiver) as y, 
       max(f_msg_date) as date
    from ch_messages
    group by sender, receiver
)
```

but it get all the messenges from a user to the current user and the current user's last message to the user.
[I want it like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmDNn.png)

This is my table structure

```
mid  => messages id
sender  => The sender of the message
receiver => The receiver of the message
msg   => The message sent
f_msg_date => date in which the message was sent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to remove the quote around reciver  in subquery and
assuming the each message have an unique id column (auto increment)  if you want the last  message

```
  select *
  from ch_messages
  where receiver='$current_user_id' 
  or sender='$current_user_id' 
  AND ( id, least(sender, receiver), greatest(sender, receiver), f_msg_date )     
  in 
  (  select 
           max(id) 
         , least(sender, receiver) 
         , greatest(sender, receiver), 
           max(f_msg_date) 
      from ch_messages
      group by sender, receiver
  )
```

Comment: I have but it displays all the messages including the current user's messages to others. but i want the current user's message , if it's a last message, should be a reply

Comment: @ClementSam   . have update the answer hope is what you need  or lead you to the correct result

Comment: each message has a unique id. i have updated the query but it give an error.

Comment: @ClementSam   show me the exact error message please

Comment: #1241 - Operand should contain 4 column(s) - From phpmyadmin

Comment: @ClementSam  i have slightly update (removind unuseful alias)  the answer  but i checked that is syntactically correct .. the operand are 4  .. check the code  provided

Comment: i think there should be an IF- statement in the query, maybe the subquery, but i dont know how. i want it like "if the sender is the current user, then the receiver should be the sender". Can u please help?

Comment: @ClementSam  .. yes i can help  ..for this .. update  youe question and add a proper data sample  and the expected  reseul  ..so i can understand you exact ..

Comment: @ClementSam  the img is not useful ..  .. show a tabular  data sample and a tabular expected .. result